# SONY SmartWatch firmware download utility

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch, winusb, dfu

In order to download the sample firmware to Smartwatch, what softwares are required? It may include dfu-util and WinUSB driver.

I tried WinUSB 1.2.6 and dfu-util, but it said:

```
K:\>dfu-util -l
dfu-util 0.7

Copyright 2005-2008 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2012 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to dfu-util@lists.gnumonks.org

Found DFU: [0fce:f0fa] devnum=0, cfg=1, intf=0, alt=0, name="UNDEFINED"
Found DFU: [0fce:f0fa] devnum=0, cfg=1, intf=0, alt=1, name="UNDEFINED"
```

And the command of uploading f/w fails.

```
K:>dfu-util -c 1 -a 0 -s 0x08004000:1024 -U new.bin
dfu-util 0.7

Copyright 2005-2008 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2012 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to dfu-util@lists.gnumonks.org

Opening DFU capable USB device... Cannot open device
```

I wonder the version of dfu-util and WinUSB are not matched.

So I think it will be great helpful if you provide the proper web URL so we can download the correct version. Also the detailed instruction on installing drivers & uploading/downloading samples are absent.

Answer (score 0):

Try Zadig http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwdi/files/zadig/ for install WinUSB.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Windows instruction for [the Arduino SmartWatch project on GitHub](https://github.com/underverk/SmartWatch/blob/master/README.md). There I think you can find one alternative for getting started with dfu-util for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. USB device is listed but you don't have the permissions to access it. On `Linux` you could just pass this one `sudo dfu-utils -l`, on Windows I didn't try but you should be able to run it as `Administrator`. Of couse best would be to fix permissions, but I can't say how on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

dfu-util is not built against any specific version of WinUSB, so the version is not important. Does your device show up as a WinUSB device in the Windows device manager?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the drivers installed and/or your watch isn't in DFU mode.

Follow the instructions here to get the watch in DFU mode (It takes a few tries to get the timing right to get the watch to boot into the mode):
http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/open-smartwatch-project/how-to-flash-alternative-firmware-to-smartwatch/

Now go here to download "SmartWatch IDE Alpha-002 - Windows" and install the driver located in there.
https://github.com/underverk/SmartWatch/wiki/Installing-the-IDE

Then check the device manager(Should look like image at the below if you got it right):

[image: Device manager showing smartwatch installed.]

Then dfu-util.exe -l should look something like this if everything is working right.

Found DFU: [0fce:f0fa] devnum=0, cfg=1, intf=0, alt=0, name="@Internal Flash   /0x08000000/03*016Ka,01*016Kg,01*064Kg,07*128Kg"
Found DFU: [0fce:f0fa] devnum=0, cfg=1, intf=0, alt=1, name="@OTP Area   /0x1FFF7800/01*512 g,01*016 g"